# Create a "controlled" APT proxy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt, repository

Do you have any experience/scrips creating a controlled APT proxy (*)?
Currently, I'm using [apt-cacher](http://www.nick-andrew.net/projects/apt-cacher/) to speed up installs/updates in my LAN, but as its name says, it's only a cache (and a good one for my needs).
The only drawback is that I don't know how to freeze a specific set of packages for the cache/repository to control updates.
Almost certainly, apt-cacher isn't the right tool for this jobs so, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Humber

> (*) An APT repository that has only
>   specific packages and updates to
>   control the OS that uses that
>   repository. I named this way because I
>   don't know if it has another name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create your own apt repo with reprepro debian (ubuntu?) package, and then add the repo's url to the sources.list of client boxes.

Reprepro howto: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/286

Comment: Thanks sntg. That's exactly what I was looking for.
I'll give it a try and let you know how all went.